# Why postman test cannot pass after converting to k6 script

Tags: node.js, k6

I have this very simple postman request that has a single pm.test(). This passes fine when running from postman. After converting to k6 script, it does not pass. I can't figure it out. What is wrong with it? Using the postman-to-k6 npm module.

[image: postman collection after converting to k6 script format]

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. K6 is converting all custom header parameters as lower case. This breaks on the server side where it expects headerVal but is being passed in as headerval.